# Apply parameter twice with Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Basically what I need is to replace this `(x) => f(x)(x)` with a functional point free approach using Ramda.

Is there a way to to do it?

Comment: This is usually called `join`, which collapses two layers of monadic computation. For the function type it is implemented as `const join = f => x => f(x) (x)`. Although we talk about binary functions for convenience, it is really a sequence of two unary functions, ie. two functional layers. `join` takes that sequence and yields a single unary function: `(r -> r -> a) -> (r -> a)`. Ramda uses join for converting `Array` to `String`, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ramda, you can utilise [`R.unnest`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#unnest) (often `join` in other languages). While this is commonly used to flatten a nested list, as pointed out in @ftor's comment, it can also act on the Chain instance for functions.

```
unnest :: Chain c => c (c a) -> c a

-- when used with lists
unnest :: [[a]] -> [a]

-- when used with functions
unnest :: (r -> r -> a) -> (r -> a)
```

Here's an example of producing a function that squares a given number by passing `R.multiply` to `R.unnest`:

```js
const sq = R.unnest(R.multiply)

console.log(sq(5)) //=> 25
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I didn't understand why it works, or why it is equivalent to `R.chain(R.identity)`, but it does work.

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz: you can see the implementation of the monad instance for functions in Ramda [here](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/source/chain.js#L33-L35). Given `R.unnest` is simply implemented as `R.chain(R.identity)`, you can swap out `fn` with `identity` and `monad` with your function in `fn(monad(x))(x)` then you're just left with the function that you're looking for.

Comment: Is `R.chain(R.identity)(f)` equivalent to `R.flatten(f)`? if `R.flatten` worked on functions (since `R.chain` is the famous `flatMap`). If it is, it's definitely not obvious that this is the behavior for flattening a function.

Comment: I just read here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#fmap_and_join and apparently `join` is the other name for `flatten`. Still, I don't get how `flatten` on a function would be equivalent to `f(x)(x)`

Comment: Just to clarify, it is `R.unnest` you want rather than `R.flattern`, which a slightly different function that only operates on lists. Perhaps another way to help see how a function can be `unnest`ed or `join`ed is the looking at the types specialised to functions with some extra parenthesis for emphasis: `unnest :: (r -> (r -> a)) -> (r -> a)`

Comment: And if you swap `R.flatten` for `R.unnest` in your comment then you're also correct about `R.chain(R.identity)(f)` being equivalent to `R.unnest(f)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `chain` directly, by combining with `identity`.

```js
const f = (x) => (y) => `f(${x})(${y})`

console.log(R.chain(f, R.identity)('x'))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```